# Creating a DLL to load a form (splash screen) in visual basic 2017

Tags: vb.net

I am new to coding so forgive me.

I wanted to code a DLL with a function which on calling produces a splash screen

My idea was to have a DLL(mydll.dll) with a form (which I will design in the form of a splash screen) calling function

So,

I created a new project and 
Class library(.NET framework)
Right click the project and selected Add ---> Windows Form

Added Form1.vb to the project

The code I used:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Class1

    Public Function Splash()
        Dim xForm As New Form1

        xForm.Show()
        xForm.Visible = True
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Then after this, the build was successful.
I tested the DLL with command prompt

```
rundll32.exe mydll.dll splash
```

It just displays the error

```
Error in mydll.dll
Missing entry splash
```

and no form is displayed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Already done. It is in C# but you can make it also work in VB.NET https://www.codeproject.com/articles/5454/a-pretty-good-splash-screen-in-c

Comment: I needed a dll. I am a newbie and needed a vb code. Dont know C#

Comment: .NET DLLs do not work the same way native DLLs do. For starters, in native DLLs you can write functions without putting them in a class. In order to run your `Splash()` method you would first need to create an instance of `Class1`, so you can most likely not run .NET DLLs through `rundll32`.

Comment: Reference your DLL in an actual .NET application instead and call `Class1.Splash()` to test it.